# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: returns different results on different iOS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITableView` with a prototype cell, whose height I am calculating using the following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1;
}
```

The cell I'm dequeuing inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only has a `UILabel` in it and I'm setting an NSAttributedString as its text.

The problem is, when I run this on a iOS 7.1 simulator, everything works perfect. However, when I run it on a iOS 8.4 simulator, this returns a larger height so there is excessive space on the bottom of the cell. What might be causing this? Any comment or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Try measuring the height of the whole cell instead maybe?

Comment: Calculating the height manually yields the same results.

Comment: on a side note layoutIfNeeded is probably a noop here, e.g no call to setNeedsLayout